# Is there a way to have selected tags combine to show only items matching all tags?

Tags: javascript, filtering

I'm working on a simple meeting listing display, search, and filter application in React.

The code is set up to filter the results (pulled from a Google Sheet) with various "tags". Each additional tag, however, works as a union, not an intersection adding more entries instead of whittling them down.

```
  //filter meetings based on selected tags
  if (tags.length) {
    meetings = meetings.filter(meeting => {
      for (let i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
        if (meeting.tags.includes(tags[i])) return true;
        console.log(tags[i])
      }
      return false;
    });
  }
```

I was looking for some way to swap out the "includes" function for something that requires all the selected tags to be present in the entry for it to show.

The full code can be seen here: https://github.com/abhinemani/oiaa

Comment: please refer to the exact path in the repository to help you with

Answer (score 0):

```
cosnt entryTagsArray = [...];

const selectedTagsArray = [...];

const isAllAvailable =  entryTagsArray.every(selectedTagsArray)
```

not sure about what you need , but
this code will check for all tags inside the array to be present in another one and then will return true or false based on situation , i hope it works

Comment: doesn't `every` receive a callback as parameter?

Comment: arr.every(callback(element[, index[, array]])[, thisArg])

Answer (score 0):

[Array.prototype.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) tests whether all elements in array pass the predicate.

> Note that `Array.prototype.every()` returns true for empty arrays, so you may want to add a check for meeting tags length too:

```js
var tags = [1,2,3];
var meetings = [{ id: 0, tags: [1,2]}, {id: 1, tags: [1,2,3]}, {id: 2, tags:[1]}, {id: 3, tags: []}, {id: 4, tags: [1,2,3] }];

meetings = meetings.filter(meeting =>
 !tags.length || tags.every((tag) =>
        meeting.tags && meeting.tags.length && meeting.tags.includes(tag)
        )
);

console.log(meetings);
```